# Optional array vs. empty array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

I have a simple `Person` class in Swift that looks about like this:

```
class Person {
    var name = "John Doe"
    var age = 18
    var children = [Person]?

    \\ init function goes here, but does not initialize children array
}
```

Instead of declaring `children` to be an optional array, I could simply declare it and initialize it as an empty array like this:

```
var children = [Person]()
```

I am trying to decide which approach is better. Declaring the array as an optional array means that it will not take up any memory at all, whereas an empty array has at least some memory allocated for it, correct? So using the optional array means that there will be at least some memory saving. I guess my first question is: Is there really any actual memory saving involved here, or are my assumptions about this incorrect?

On the other hand, if it is optional then each time I try to use it I will have to check to see if it is `nil` or not before adding or removing objects from it. So there will be be some loss of efficiency there (but not much, I imagine).

I kind of like the optional approach. Not every `Person` will have children, so why not let `children` be `nil` until the `Person` decides to settle down and raise a family?

At any rate, I would like to know if there are any other specific advantages or disadvantages to one approach or the other. It is a design question that will come up over and over again.

Comment: You have a valid question, but I think the arguments for and against are dangerous - based on premature optimization and not semantics.  It is far better to focus on the "affordance" of the code - how much it suggests the intent (whatever that may be for the context).  There are a bunch of things I don't like about Swift, but to me, the Optional type is a real gem. While there is no "right" answer for your question, I use it extensively in contexts like yours.  Using an optional for the case of optional children seems entirely reasonable and minimalist.

Comment: I would assume that the count of items in the array being zero means there are zero children. A nil array would suggest that there is a number of children that cannot be zero and cannot be non-zero. There is no logic in returning nil since there is no meaning in it. Having had to maintain code that was written 20 years earlier, I can tell you that if you suggest some other meaning by returning nil, some one will be confused by it and wonder what you intended to do with that nil that an empty array did not accomplish. performance of the empty array is not likely to matter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The ability to choose between an empty array or an optional gives us the ability to apply the one that better describe the data from a semantic point of view.

I would choose:

- An empty array if the list can be empty, but it's a transient status and in the end it should have at least one element. Being non optional makes clear that the array should not be empty
- An optional if it's possible for the list to be empty for the entire life cycle of the container entity. Being an optional makes clear that the array can be empty

Let me make some examples:

- Purchase order with master and details (one detail per product): a purchase order can have 0 details, but that's a transient status, because it wouldn't make sense having a purchase order with 0 products
- Person with children: a person can have no children for his entire life. It is not a transient status (although not permanent as well), but using an optional it's clear that it's legit for a person to have no children.

Note that my opinion is only about making the code more clear and self-explainatory - I don't think there is any significant difference in terms of performance, memory usage, etc. for choosing one option or the other.

Comment: The count of items in the array is the number of children. Zero items is zero children. Using nil for the array implies a count that is neither zero nor non-zero, which is almost nonsense. The only case where nil might make sense is if you want to pass on to the caller that the number cannot be calculated (is unknown), which is the only other state possible. Return the number of children if the number is known and return it by having that many items in the array.

Comment: "An optional if it's possible for the list to be empty for the entire life cycle of the container entity" 

That's something I would never think so using nil for that is not intuitive and would require a comment. In fact, any use of nil would require some code comments making me think it's better to just not use it and return an empty array, which is totally clear and needs no code comments to understand.

Answer (score 23):

I'm going to make the opposite case from Yordi - an empty array just as clearly says "this Person has no children", and will save you a ton of hassle. `children.isEmpty` is an easy check for the existence of kids, and you won't ever have to unwrap or worry about an unexpected `nil`.

Also, as a note, declaring something as optional doesn't mean it takes zero space - it's the `.None` case of an `Optional<Array<Person>>`.

Comment: Completely agree. Making it optional also forces to make two check if we *really* want to know if there is more than 1 child (unwrap then check if it’s not empty), which slightly complicates the code without real benefits. Empty array is clear in my opinion.

Comment: I wonder about performance issues, if I have a heavy class, will an array of this type be a big overhead compared to a .None? Or is there any optimization in Swift not to allocate space for initially empty arrays?

Answer (score 15):

Interestingly enough, we have recently had few discussions regarding this very same question at work.

Some suggest that there are subtle semantic differences. E.g. `nil` means a person has no children whatsoever, but then what does `0` mean? Does it mean *"has children, the whole 0 of them"*? Like I said, pure semantics *"has 0 children"* and *"has no children"* makes no difference when working with this model in code. In that case why not choosing more straightforwards and less guard-let-?-y approach?

Some suggest that keeping a `nil` there may be an indication that, for example, when fetching model from backend something went wrong and we got error instead of children. But I think model should not try to have this type of semantics and `nil` should not be used as indication of some error in the past.

I personally think that the model should be as dumb as possible and the *dumbest* option in this case is empty array.

Having an optional will make you drag that `?` until the end of days and use `guard let`, `if let` or `??` over and over again.

You will have to have extra unwrapping logic for `NSCoding` implementation, you will have to do `person.children?.count ?? 0` instead of straightforward `person.children.count` when you display that model in any view controller.

The final goal of all that manipulation is to display something on UI.
Would you really say

"This person has no children" and "This person has 0 children" for `nil` and empty array correspondingly? I hope you would not :)

## Last Straw

Finally, and this is really the strongest argument I have

- What is the type of `subviews` property of `UIView`: [it's `var subviews: [UIView] { get }`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/subviews)
- What is the type of `children` property of `SKNode`: [it's `var children: [SKNode] { get }`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/children)

There's tons of examples like this in Cocoa framework: [UIViewController::childViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/childViewControllers) and more.

Even from pure Swift world: [Dictionary::keys](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/Dictionary/#comment-var-keys_-lazymapcollection-key_-value-key) though this may be a bit far fetched.

Why is it OK for person to have `nil` children, but not for `SKNode`? For me the analogy is perfect. Hey, even the `SKNode`'s method name is `children` :)

My view: there must be an obvious reason for keeping those arrays as optionals, like a really good one, otherwise empty array offers same semantics with less unwrapping.

## The Last Last Straw

Finally, some references to very good articles, each of those

- http://www.theswiftlearner.com/2015/05/08/empty-or-optional-arrays/
- https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-optional-vs-empty-data-source-swift/

In Natasha's post, you will find a [link to NSHipster's blog post](http://nshipster.com/ios9/) and in *Swiftification* paragraph you can read this:

> For example, instead of marking NSArray return values as nullable, many APIs have been modified to return an empty array—semantically these have the same value (i.e., nothing), but a non-optional array is far simpler to work with

Comment: "nil" to me is the null in the database ( same as java's and c#'s nulls).  It means that we don't know if the  person has children or not.  A value of  0 means that we know that the person has no children.

Comment: @chrisl08, that's a good example where `nil` makes sense in problem domain. I'd still argue that if there's no need to model the "we don't know" or similar state, then there's no need to use `nil`. E.g. in banking apps, we (the bank) definitely know that client has accounts, so `nil` and empty array would have same semantics. Same with `SKNode`, the `SpriteKit` framework _knows for sure_ whether a node has children or not, so they model it as empty array.

Comment: totally agree and that is why they give us the option to mark a column as nullable in rdbms systems and why it was necessary to have nullable variables in programming languages like swift/java/c# etc

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes there's a difference between something not existing and being empty.

Let's say we have an app where a user can modify a list of phone numbers and we save said modifications as `modifiedPhoneNumberList`. If no modification has ever occurred the array should be nil. If the user has modified the parsed numbers by deleting them all the array should be empty.

Empty means we're going to delete all the existing phone numbers, nil means we keep all the existing phone numbers. The difference matters here.

When we can't differentiate between a property being empty or not existing or it doesn't matter empty is the way to go. If a `Person` were to lose their only child we should simply have to remove that child and have an empty array rather than have to check if the `count` is 1 then set the entire array to `nil`.

Comment: This. Having optionals lets you also understand (to a certain extent) the history of a variable. Like Deco said, if you have an optional children array which at some point is empty, it means the Person has had kids, but somehow lost them at some point. In UI terms, you could then differentiate 'Person never had children' from 'Person does not have any children anymore'

Answer (score 3):

I always use empty arrays.

In my humble opinion, the most important purpose of optionals in Swift is to safely wrap some value that may be nil. An array already act as this type of wrapper - you can ask the array if it has anything inside & access its value(s) safely with for loops, mapping, etc. Do we need to put a wrapper within a wrapper? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift is designed to take advantage of optional value's and optional unwrapping.**

You ***could*** also declare the array as nil, as it will save you a very small (almost not noticable) amount of memory.

I would go with an optional array instead of an array that represents a nil value to keep Swift's Design Patterns happy :)

I also think

```
if let children = children {

}
```

looks nicer than :

```
if(children != nil){

}
```