# Swiftui - dynamic PageTabView hierarchical

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am struggling to find a solution for my problem and don't actually know how to approach this.
I am trying to display a hierarchical (4 levels) sort of beverage menu. It should look and feel like you are reading a book and by swiping changing the current site you are at.

You can check my approach on that below.

My questions is, how does the core have to look like in order to be able to display this as mentioned.

Here are the features the app should have:
With a button below, i should be able to open a new page which shows me just the categories. When I click on a category (of any level) it should go back to the main page and show me the beginning of this exact category, displaying the products below.
Also there should be a search function for categories and products.(which also jumps to the page, the category or product is at)

My biggest problem is, that everything must be generated dynamically, because all data comes from an api and is stored in core for further use.

I chose this model type:

```
struct Category: Decodable, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var subcategories: [Category]?
    var wines: [Wine]?

}

extension Category {
    init(entity: CategoryEntity) {
        id = entity.id!
        name = entity.name ?? "unknown category name"
        subcategories = entity.subcategories?.allObjects as? [Category] ?? []
        wines = entity.wines?.allObjects as? [Wine] ?? []
    }
}

struct Wine: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String?
    var number: String
    var price: Double
    var year: String
    var categories: UUID
    var size: Double?
}
```

subcategories and wines are optional because not every category or subcategory has subcategories or wines.

My view approach:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @StateObject var wineDataModel = WineDataModel()
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if wineDataModel.categories.isEmpty {
                Text("Lade Daten...")
                    .onAppear {
                        wineDataModel.fetchCategoriesAndProducts()
                    }
            } else {
                CategoryTabView(categories: wineDataModel.categories, selectedIndex: $selectedIndex)
                Spacer()
                Rectangle()
                  .foregroundColor(.clear)
                  .frame(width: 1024, height: 40)
                  .background(Color(red: 0.85, green: 0.85, blue: 0.85))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryTabView: View {
    var categories: [Category]
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    let itemsPerPage = 10

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
            ForEach(Array(categories.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, category in
                CategoryDetailView(category: category, itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage)
                    .tag(index)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}

struct CategoryDetailView: View {
    let category: Category
    let itemsPerPage: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text(category.name)
                .font(.title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            if let subcategories = category.subcategories, !subcategories.isEmpty {
                CategoryTabView(categories: subcategories, selectedIndex: .constant(0))
            } else if let wines = category.wines, !wines.isEmpty {
                let pages = wines.chunked(into: itemsPerPage)
                TabView {
                    ForEach(Array(pages.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { pageIndex, pageWines in
                        ProductPage(wines: pageWines, pageIndex: pageIndex)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
            } else {
                Text("Keine Weine verfügbar")
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct ProductPage: View {
    let wines: [Wine]
    let pageIndex: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(wines, id: \.id) { wine in
                WineRow(wine: wine)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}

struct WineRow: View {
    let wine: Wine

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(wine.name ?? "Unbekannter Wein")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                Text(wine.year)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
            
            Text("\(wine.price, specifier: "%.2f") €")
                .frame(width: 300, alignment: .trailing)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

It kind of looks and behaves like it should, the fact that I have nested PageTabs is slowly giving me headaches.
I tried to chunk the products and generate more pages if there are more products then could fit on one page, which works perfectly. Generally I want to display all category level names and their products hierarchically.

Now my problem is that I have no clue on how to implement a @State variable, which keeps track of the current category recursively.

What is you opinion on that?
Would it work with this model structure?

On any given time I want to see the category names (all levels) and the linked products to them.
Unfortunately I have no idea on how i should implement the search function or the jumpToPage function for the categories.
As I already mentioned, the goal is to click on a button in the corner, new page with all categories displayed opens, klick on a category jump exactly to the page this category begins.

Next problem is the custom slider, which also keeps track of the page I am currently at, and by moving it should change the page.
Also I would like to implement a function to add a product to some kind of a cart. The third (bookmark) symbol should open a tab with the selected products. The bookmark symbol will also be in the same line as the wine.name.

Here is a brief overview of what the interface will look like (above that frame the categories and products are displayed)
[Interface with CustomSlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpJbI.png)

Hope you guys can help me out or give me some tips on how to approach this.

Thanks in advance!
Wayx

Comment: I would consider empty array against optional, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811787/optional-array-vs-empty-array-in-swift